# A limit problem related to $\log \sec x$

Tags: calculus, limits

> If $$f(x) = \dfrac{{\displaystyle 3\int_{0}^{x}(1 + \sec t)\log\sec t\,dt}}{(\log\sec x)\{x + \log(\sec x + \tan x)\}}$$ then prove that $$\lim_{x \to {\pi/2}^{-}}f(x) = \frac{3}{2}$$ and $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x) - 1}{x^{4}} = \frac{1}{420}$$

Looking at the integral sign in numerator I see that the best way to attack this problem is via L'Hospital Rule. <strike>But that requires to show that the integral diverges to $\infty$ as $x \to {\pi/2}^{-}$. Assuming that this is the case</strike> I solved the first limit by applying L'Hospital's rule twice. But for the second limit it seems hopeless to try L'Hospital because of denominator $x^{4}$ which might require 4 times its application.

Looking at the functions involved it does not look easy to apply Taylor's series expansions. I am not sure if there is any elegant solution for the second problem. Please let me know any hints or a solution to the second limit.

**Update**: I tried some simplification along with LHR for the second limit but still the final solution is eluding.

Let $a(x), b(x)$ be the numerator and denominator of $f(x)$. Clearly we can see that
\begin{align}
B &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{b(x)}{x^{3}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log\sec x\{x + \log(\sec x + \tan x)\}}{x^{3}}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log\cos x\{x + \log(1 + \sin x) - \log \cos x\}}{x^{3}}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log\cos x}{x^{2}}\cdot\frac{x + \log(1 + \sin x) - \log \cos x}{x}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + \cos x - 1)}{\cos x - 1}\cdot\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{2}}\cdot\frac{x + \log(1 + \sin x) - \log \cos x}{x}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x + \log(1 + \sin x) - \log \cos x}{x}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\left(1 + \frac{\log(1 + \sin x)}{\sin x}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{x} - \frac{\log (1 + \cos x - 1)}{\cos x - 1}\cdot x\cdot \frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{2}}\right)\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2 = 1\notag
\end{align}
Thus we can write
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x) - 1}{x^{4}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a(x) - b(x)}{b(x)x^{4}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a(x) - b(x)}{x^{7}}\cdot\frac{x^{3}}{b(x)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a(x) - b(x)}{x^{7}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{7}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a'(x) - b'(x)}{x^{6}}\text{ (via L'Hospital's Rule)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{7}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{3(1 + \sec x)\log\sec x - \tan x\{x + \log(\sec x + \tan x)\} -\log\sec x\{1 + \sec x\}}{x^{6}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{7}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2(1 + \sec x)\log\sec x - \tan x\{x + \log(\sec x + \tan x)\}}{x^{6}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{7}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2(1 + \cos x)\log\sec x - \sin x\{x + \log(\sec x + \tan x)\}}{x^{6}\cos x}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{7}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2(1 + \cos x)\log\sec x - \sin x\{x + \log(\sec x + \tan x)\}}{x^{6}}\notag\\
\end{align}
I wonder what could be done to go further.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? Let me know if I am missing something or if there is any room for improvement in the question.

Comment: I don't know why there was a down vote.  However, it is not clear what the brackets mean in the denominator.  Do you mean the denominator to be $\left(\log\sec x\right)\left(x + \log(\sec x + \tan x)\right)$? Or $\log\sec \left(x(x + \log(x\sec x + \tan x))\right)$?

Comment: @Michael: it means $(\log \sec x)(x + \log(\sec x + \tan x))$ I will update the question to reflect that

Comment: @Paramanand. It seems to me that the last two lines should be as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*}
&=&\frac{1}{7}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2\left( \cos x\right) (1+\cos
x)\log \sec x-\sin x\left( x+\log (\sec x+\tan x)\right) }{x^{6}\cos x} \\
&=&\frac{1}{7}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2\left( \cos x\right) (1+\cos
x)\log \sec x-\sin x\left( x+\log (\sec x+\tan x)\right) }{x^{6}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Can you confirm please?

Comment: @Idris: If you see 3rd last line it begins with $2(1 + \sec x)$ and by multiplying with $\cos x$ it becomes $2 (1 + \cos x)$ so my calculation seems ok.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. Sorry I did not see that $sec$ becomes $cos$.

Comment: @Michael: You need to take care that the limit has to be taken when $x \to \pi/2$ and $x < \pi/2$. Then you will get using LHR the limit as $3/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x) &=&2(1+\cos x)\log \sec x-\sin x\{x+\log (\sec x+\tan x)\} \\
&=&\{\sin x-2(1+\cos x)\}\log \cos x-x\sin x-\sin x\log (1+\sin x) \\
&=&\{\sin x-2(1+\cos x)\}A(x)-B(x)-C(x)
\end{eqnarray*}
where
\begin{eqnarray*}
A(x) &=&\log \cos x \\
B(x) &=&x\sin x \\
C(x) &=&\sin x\log (1+\sin x)
\end{eqnarray*}

Let us start with $B(x).$
\begin{eqnarray*}
B(x) &=&x\sin x \\
&=&x\left[ \sin x-x+\frac{1}{6}x^{3}+x-\frac{1}{6}x^{3}\right]  \\
&=&x\left[ \sin x-x+\frac{1}{6}x^{3}\right] +x^{2}-\frac{1}{6}x^{4} \\
&=&x^{6}\left( \frac{\sin x-x+\frac{1}{6}x^{3}}{x^{5}}\right) +x^{2}-\frac{1%
}{6}x^{4}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now let us consider in the same lines $A(x)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
A(x) &=&\log \cos x \\
&=&\log (1+(\cos x-1))-(\cos x-1)+\frac{1}{2}(\cos x-1)^{2} \\
&&+(\cos x-1)-\frac{1}{2}(\cos x-1)^{2} \\
&=&\left( \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log (1+(\cos x-1))-(\cos x-1)+\frac{1}{%
2}(\cos x-1)^{2}}{(\cos x-1)^{3}}\right) \left( \frac{\cos x-1}{x^{2}}%
\right) ^{3}\left( x^{6}\right)  \\
&&+(\cos x-1)-\frac{1}{2}(\cos x-1)^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
It remains $C(x)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
C(x) &=&\sin x\log (1+\sin x) \\
&=&\sin x(\log (1+\sin x)-\sin x+\frac{1}{2}\sin ^{2}x-\frac{1}{3}\sin ^{3}x+%
\frac{1}{4}\sin ^{4}x \\
&&+\sin x-\frac{1}{2}\sin ^{2}x+\frac{1}{3}\sin ^{3}x-\frac{1}{4}\sin ^{4}x)
\\
&=&\sin x\left( \log (1+\sin x)-\sin x+\frac{1}{2}\sin ^{2}x-\frac{1}{3}\sin
^{3}x+\frac{1}{4}\sin ^{4}x\right)  \\
&&+\sin ^{2}x-\frac{1}{2}\sin ^{3}x+\frac{1}{3}\sin ^{4}x-\frac{1}{4}\sin
^{5}x \\
&=&(x^{6})\left( \frac{\sin x}{x}\right) ^{6}\left( \frac{\log (1+\sin
x)-\sin x+\frac{1}{2}\sin ^{2}x-\frac{1}{3}\sin ^{3}x+\frac{1}{4}\sin ^{4}x}{%
\sin ^{5}x}\right)  \\
&&+\sin ^{2}x-\frac{1}{2}\sin ^{3}x+\frac{1}{3}\sin ^{4}x-\frac{1}{4}\sin
^{5}x.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now let us write the resulting expression of $g(x)$ as follows
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x) &=&\{\sin x-2(1+\cos x)\}A(x)-B(x)-C(x) \\
&=&\{\sin x-2(1+\cos x)\}\left( \frac{\log (1+(\cos x-1))-(\cos x-1)+\frac{1%
}{2}(\cos x-1)^{2}}{(\cos x-1)^{3}}\right) \left( \frac{\cos x-1}{x^{2}}%
\right) ^{3}\left( x^{6}\right)  \\
&&+\{\sin x-2(1+\cos x)\}\{(\cos x-1)-\frac{1}{2}(\cos x-1)^{2}\} \\
&&-\left( x^{6}\right) \left( \frac{\sin x-x+\frac{1}{6}x^{3}}{x^{5}}\right)
-x^{2}+\frac{1}{6}x^{4} \\
&&-(x^{6})\left( \frac{\sin x}{x}\right) ^{6}\left( \frac{\log (1+\sin
x)-\sin x+\frac{1}{2}\sin ^{2}x-\frac{1}{3}\sin ^{3}x+\frac{1}{4}\sin ^{4}x}{%
\sin ^{5}x}\right)  \\
&&-\sin ^{2}x+\frac{1}{2}\sin ^{3}x-\frac{1}{3}\sin ^{4}x+\frac{1}{4}\sin
^{5}x.
\end{eqnarray*}
Divide $g(x)$ by $x^{6}$ it follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{g(x)}{x^{6}} &=&\left( \sin x-2(1+\cos x)\right) \left( \frac{\log
(1+(\cos x-1))-(\cos x-1)+\frac{1}{2}(\cos x-1)^{2}}{(\cos x-1)^{3}}\right)
\left( \frac{\cos x-1}{x^{2}}\right) ^{3} \\
&&-\left( \frac{\sin x-x+\frac{1}{6}x^{3}}{x^{5}}\right) -\left( \frac{\sin x%
}{x}\right) ^{6}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{\log (1+\sin x)-\sin x+%
\frac{1}{2}\sin ^{2}x-\frac{1}{3}\sin ^{3}x+\frac{1}{4}\sin ^{4}x}{\sin ^{5}x%
}\right)  \\
&&+((\sin x-2(1+\cos x))((\cos x-1)-\frac{1}{2}(\cos x-1)^{2}) \\
&&-x^{2}+\frac{1}{6}x^{4}-\sin ^{2}x+\frac{1}{2}\sin ^{3}x-\frac{1}{3}\sin
^{4}x+\frac{1}{4}\sin ^{5}x)/x^{6}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let 
\begin{eqnarray*}
h(x) &=&\{\sin x-2(1+\cos x)\}\{(\cos x-1)-\frac{1}{2}(\cos x-1)^{2}\}
\\
&&-x^{2}+\frac{1}{6}x^{4}-\sin ^{2}x+\frac{1}{2}\sin ^{3}x-\frac{1}{3}\sin
^{4}x+\frac{1}{4}\sin ^{5}x.
\end{eqnarray*}
It remains just to prove that 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(x)}{x^{6}}=\frac{7}{120}
\end{equation*}
which is an easy computation (with or without) using LHR.

${\bf UPDATE:}$ 
The purpose of the first steps previously done reduced the computation of the limit of $%
\frac{g(x)}{x^{6}}$ which is a complicated expression to the computation of
the limit of $\frac{h(x)}{x^{6}}$ which is very simple comparatively to $%
\frac{g(x)}{x^{6}}.$ Indeed, one can use the l'Hospital's rule six times
very easily, but before starting to do the derivations some trigonometric
simplifications are used as follows. This is

\begin{equation*}
h(x)=(\sin x-2(1+\cos x))((\cos x-1)-\frac{1}{2}(\cos x-1)^{2})-x^{2}+\frac{1%
}{6}x^{4}-\sin ^{2}x+\frac{1}{2}\sin ^{3}x-\frac{1}{3}\sin ^{4}x+\frac{1}{4}%
\sin ^{5}x.
\end{equation*}

Develop the product of the first two parenthesis and next simplifying and
using power-reduction formulas
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Multiple-angle_formulae)
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
\sin ^{2}\theta =\frac{1-\cos 2\theta }{2} &  & \cos ^{2}\theta =\frac{%
1+\cos 2\theta }{2} \\ 
\sin ^{3}\theta =\frac{3\sin \theta -\sin 3\theta }{4} &  & \cos ^{3}\theta =%
\frac{3\cos \theta +\cos 3\theta }{4} \\ 
\sin ^{4}\theta =\frac{3-4\cos 2\theta +\cos 4\theta }{8} &  & \cos
^{4}\theta =\frac{3+4\cos 2\theta +\cos 4\theta }{8} \\ 
\sin ^{5}\theta =\frac{10\sin \theta -5\sin 3\theta +\sin 5\theta }{16} &  & 
\cos ^{5}\theta =\frac{10\cos \theta +5\cos 3\theta +\cos 5\theta }{16}%
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

one then can re-write $h(x)\ $as follows
\begin{equation*}
h(x)=\frac{1}{6}x^{4}-\frac{35}{32}\sin x-x^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\cos x-\frac{5}{6}%
\cos 2x+\frac{1}{4}\cos 3x- \frac{1}{24}\cos 4x+\sin 2x-\frac{21}{%
64}\sin 3x+\frac{1}{64}\sin 5x+\frac{7}{8} 
\end{equation*}

and therefore derivatives are simply calculated (because there is no power
on the top of sin and cos), so 
\begin{equation*}
h^{\prime }(x)=\frac{1}{4}\sin x-\frac{35}{32}\cos x-2x+\frac{2}{3}%
x^{3}+2\cos 2x-\frac{63}{64}\cos 3x+ \frac{5}{64}\cos 5x+\frac{5}{%
3}\sin 2x-\frac{3}{4}\sin 3x+\frac{1}{6}\sin 4x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
h^{\prime \prime }(x)=\frac{1}{4}\cos x+\frac{35}{32}\sin x+2x^{2}+\frac{10}{%
3}\cos 2x-\frac{9}{4}\cos 3x+ \frac{2}{3}\cos 4x-4\sin 2x+\frac{%
189}{64}\sin 3x-\frac{25}{64}\sin 5x- 2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
h^{\prime \prime \prime }(x)=4x+\frac{35}{32}\cos x-\frac{1}{4}\sin x-8\cos
2x+\frac{567}{64}\cos 3x- \frac{125}{64}\cos 5x-\frac{20}{3}\sin
2x+\frac{27}{4}\sin 3x-\frac{8}{3}\sin 4x 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
h^{(4)}(x)=\frac{81}{4}\cos 3x-\frac{35}{32}\sin x-\frac{40}{3}\cos 2x-\frac{%
1}{4}\cos x-\frac{32}{3} \cos 4x+16\sin 2x-\frac{1701}{64}\sin 3x+%
\frac{625}{64}\sin 5x+4
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
h^{(5)}(x)=\frac{1}{4}\sin x-\frac{35}{32}\cos x+32\cos 2x-\frac{5103}{64}%
\cos 3x+ \frac{3125}{64}\cos 5x+\frac{80}{3}\sin 2x-\frac{243}{4}%
\sin 3x+\frac{128}{3}\sin 4x 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
h^{(6)}(x)=\frac{1}{4}\cos x+\frac{35}{32}\sin x+\frac{160}{3}\cos 2x-\frac{%
729}{4}\cos 3x+ \frac{512}{3}\cos 4x-64\sin 2x+\frac{15\,309}{64}%
\sin 3x-\frac{15\,625}{64} \sin 5x
\end{equation*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(x)}{x^{6}} &=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{%
h^{\prime }(x)}{6x^{5}}=\cdots =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{h^{(6)}(x)}{6!}=%
\frac{h^{(6)}(0)}{6!} \\
&=&\frac{1}{6!}\left( \frac{1}{4}\cos (0)+\frac{160}{3}\cos (0)-\frac{729}{4}%
\cos (0)+ \frac{512}{3}\cos (0)\right)  \\
&=&\frac{1}{6!}\left( \frac{1}{4}+\frac{160}{3}-\frac{729}{4}+\frac{512}{3}%
\right)  \\
&=&\frac{7}{120}.
\end{eqnarray*}
By the way, one have to verify that at each level (except the last one) the
current derivative is $zero$ for $x=0,$ in order to be able to re-use LHR.

Comment: @paramanand. I have skipped some explanations related to standard limits because I believe they are evident for you.

Comment: See an approach based on Taylor series in my answer.

Comment: The computation you have done are based on Taylor series expansions of $\sin x, \cos x, \log(1 + x)$ and are are bit too lengthy. Also the expression $h(x)$ at the end of your answer seems complicated and I believe calculation of limit of $h(x)/x^{6}$ is also a bit laborious. I am still looking for a cleaner solution. +1 for these heavy computations by the way.

Comment: @Paramanand The calculation of the limit of $h(x)/x^6$ by LHR are very easy. I can do them if you want. If you want them without LHR they will be somewhat lengthy but this due to the higher order $x^6$. For me, the heart of the solution is the first part I did yesterday because of the manipulations I did are not usual.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. Concerning the first step of yesterday, I mean the reduction of computation of limit of $g(x)/x^6$ to the computation of the limit of $h(x)/x^6$, it is possible to use Taylor series in the same fashion as I did my manipulations.  Also, I hope this time you are convinced that the computation of the limit of $h(x)/x^6$ is simple (and lengthy because the higher order is involved  $x^6$.) I am happy to have contributed in these calculations. In doing so, I am now able to compute a limit which is still opened, I have asked months ago it is about $(tan(sin(x))-sin(tan(x)))/x^7$.

Comment: That limit $\tan(\sin x) - \sin(\tan x)$ seems impossible via LHR. I had spent sometime on it but not yet successful in this manner.

Comment: @Paramanand I did it, please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025548/lim-x-to-0-fracx3-sin2x-tan-x-tan-sin-x-sin-tan-x/1329971#1329971

Answer (score 1):

Here is my work for the first limit:  Let $f(x) = \frac{num(x)}{den(x)}$. We get $\infty/\infty$ so we can use L'Hopital:

\begin{align*}
\frac{num'(x)}{den'(x)}&=\frac{3(1+\sec(x))\log \sec x}{(\tan(x))(x  + \log(\sec x + \tan x))  + (\log \sec (x)) (1 + \sec(x)) }\\
&= \frac{3(1+\sec(x))\log \sec x}{(\tan(x))[x + (\log \sec x) +\log(1+\sin(x))] + (\log \sec x)(1+\sec(x)) )}\\
&= \frac{3}{\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{1+\sec(x)}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x + \log(1 + \sin(x))}{\log \sec x}\right)+ 1}
\end{align*}
Taking a limit as $x\rightarrow \pi/2^-$ gives $3/2$.

Comment: See an approach based on Taylor series in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

While I am still searching for a simple solution based on LHR, I found that method of Taylor series can also be applied without much difficulty. However we will need to make the substitution $\tan x = t$ so that $\sec x = \sqrt{1 + t^{2}}$ and as $x \to 0$ we also have $t \to 0$. We can do some simplification as follows
\begin{align}
A &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2(1 + \sec x)\log \sec x - \tan x\{x + \log(\sec x + \tan x)\}}{x^{6}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(1 + \sec x)\log(1 + \tan^{2}x) - \tan x\{x + \log(\sec x + \tan x)\}}{\tan^{6}x}\cdot\frac{\tan^{6}x}{x^{6}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{(1 + \sqrt{1 + t^{2}})\log(1 + t^{2}) - t\{\tan^{-1}t + \log(t + \sqrt{1 + t^{2}})\}}{t^{6}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{g(t) - h(t)}{t^{6}}\notag
\end{align}
The Taylor series expansions of functions in the numerator are easy to find with the exception of $\log(t + \sqrt{1 + t^{2}})$. But then we know that
\begin{align}
\log(t + \sqrt{1 + t^{2}}) &= \int_{0}^{t}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 + x^{2}}}\notag\\
&= \int_{0}^{t}\left(1 - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{3x^{4}}{8} + o(x^{4})\right)\,dx\notag\\
&= t - \frac{t^{3}}{6} + \frac{3t^{5}}{40} + o(t^{5})\notag\\
\end{align}
Thus we can see that
\begin{align}
h(t) &= t\{\tan^{-1}t + \log(t + \sqrt{1 + t^{2}})\}\notag\\
&= t\left(t - \frac{t^{3}}{3} + \frac{t^{5}}{5} + t - \frac{t^{3}}{6} + \frac{3t^{5}}{40} + o(t^{5})\right)\notag\\
&= 2t^{2} - \frac{t^{4}}{2} + \frac{11t^{6}}{40} + o(t^{6})\notag
\end{align}
And further
\begin{align}
g(t) &= (1 + \sqrt{1 + t^{2}})\log(1 + t^{2})\notag\\
&= \left(2 + \frac{t^{2}}{2} - \frac{t^{4}}{8} + o(t^{4})\right)\left(t^{2} - \frac{t^{4}}{2} + \frac{t^{6}}{3} + o(t^{6})\right)\notag\\
&= t^{2}\left(2 + \frac{t^{2}}{2} - \frac{t^{4}}{8} + o(t^{4})\right)\left(1 - \frac{t^{2}}{2} + \frac{t^{4}}{3} + o(t^{4})\right)\notag\\
&= t^{2}\left(2 - \frac{t^{2}}{2} + \frac{7t^{4}}{24} + o(t^{4})\right)\notag\\
&= 2t^{2} - \frac{t^{4}}{2} + \frac{7t^{6}}{24} + o(t^{6})\notag
\end{align}
It is now clear that $$A = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{g(t) - h(t)}{t^{6}} = \frac{7}{24} - \frac{11}{40} = \frac{35 - 33}{120} = \frac{1}{60}$$ and hence $$L = \frac{A}{7} = \frac{1}{420}$$
Getting rid of trigonometric functions $\sec x, \tan x$ does help in having simpler Taylor series which require very little amount of calculation. The only trigonometric function is $\tan^{-1}t$ which has the simplest Taylor series.

---

Another perhaps simpler approach via Taylor series would be to use the series for $\sec x, \tan x$ followed by integration (to get series for $\log \sec x$, $\log(\sec x + \tan x)$) and thus finding a Taylor series for $f(x)$ directly leading to $$f(x) = 1 + \frac{x^{4}}{420} + o(x^{4})$$ Thus we can start with $$\tan x = x + \frac{x^{3}}{3} + \frac{2x^{5}}{15} + o(x^{5})$$ and $$\sec x = \dfrac{1}{\cos x} = \dfrac{1}{1 - \dfrac{x^{2}}{2} + \dfrac{x^{4}}{24} + o(x^{4})} = 1 + \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{5x^{4}}{24} + o(x^{4})$$ and on integrating the series for $\tan x, \sec x$ we get
\begin{align}
\log \sec x &= \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{4}}{12} + \frac{x^{6}}{45} + o(x^{6})\notag\\
\log(\sec x + \tan x) &= x + \frac{x^{3}}{6} + \frac{x^{5}}{24} + o(x^{5})\notag\\
\Rightarrow (1 + \sec t)\log \sec t &= \left(2 + \frac{t^{2}}{2} + \frac{5t^{4}}{24} + o(t^{4})\right)\left(\frac{t^{2}}{2} + \frac{t^{4}}{12} + \frac{t^{6}}{45} + o(t^{6})\right)\notag\\
&= t^{2}\left(2 + \frac{t^{2}}{2} + \frac{5t^{4}}{24} + o(t^{4})\right)\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{t^{2}}{12} + \frac{t^{4}}{45} + o(t^{4})\right)\notag\\
&= t^{2}\left(1 + \frac{5t^{2}}{12} + \frac{137t^{4}}{720} + o(t^{4})\right)\notag\\
&= t^{2} + \frac{5t^{4}}{12} + \frac{137t^{6}}{720} + o(t^{6})\notag
\end{align}
It follows that $$a(x) = 3\int_{0}^{x}(1 + \sec t)\log\sec t\,dt = x^{3}\left(1 + \frac{x^{2}}{4} + \frac{137x^{4}}{1680} + o(x^{4})\right)$$ and
\begin{align}
b(x) &= \{x + \log(\sec x + \tan x)\}\log \sec x\notag\\
&= \left(2x + \frac{x^{3}}{6} + \frac{x^{5}}{24} + o(x^{5})\right)\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{4}}{12} + \frac{x^{6}}{45} + o(x^{6})\right)\notag\\
&= x^{3}\left(2 + \frac{x^{2}}{6} + \frac{x^{4}}{24} + o(x^{4})\right)\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x^{2}}{12} + \frac{x^{4}}{45} + o(x^{4})\right)\notag\\
&= x^{3}\left(1 + \frac{x^{2}}{4} + \frac{19x^{4}}{240} + o(x^{4})\right)\notag
\end{align}
Thus we can see that
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{a(x)}{b(x)} = \dfrac{1 + \dfrac{x^{2}}{4} + \dfrac{137x^{4}}{1680} + o(x^{4})}{1 + \dfrac{x^{2}}{4} + \dfrac{19x^{4}}{240} + o(x^{4})}\notag\\
&= 1 + px^{2} + qx^{4} + o(x^{4})\notag
\end{align}
where $$p + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4},\, q + \frac{p}{4} +  \frac{19}{240} = \frac{137}{1680}$$ so that $$p = 0, q = \frac{137 - 133}{1680} = \frac{4}{1680} = \frac{1}{420}$$ and finally we get $$f(x) = 1 + \frac{x^{4}}{420} + o(x^{4})$$ as desired. This however does involve the division of power series one time and multiplication of power series 2 times (not to mention the use of not so familiar Taylor series for $\sec x, \tan x$ in the first place). The first approach which I have given in my answer uses the product of two series only one time and one application of LHR (given in the question itself).