# $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0 }\frac{\sin _{n}x-x+\frac{n}{6}x^{3}-\left( \frac{ n^{2}}{24}-\frac{n}{30}\right) x^{5}}{x^{7}}$

Tags: limits

From the post [Evaluating limit (iterated sine function)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345313/evaluating-limit-iterated-sine-function)  and some discussions inside, one can collect the
following three limits 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 }\frac{\sin _{n}x}{x} &=&1 \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-\sin _{n}x}{x^{3}} &=&\frac{n}{6} \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin _{n}x-x+\frac{n}{6}x^{3}}{x^{5}} &=&%
\frac{n^{2}}{24}-\frac{n}{30}.
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\sin _{n}x=\sin (\sin \cdots (\sin x)),\ n$ times composition.

So the next question would be, what is the following limit
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin _{n}x-x+\frac{n}{6}x^{3}-\left( \frac{%
n^{2}}{24}-\frac{n}{30}\right) x^{5}}{x^{7}}
\end{equation*}
and what are those corresponding limits after order 7 $?$

Comment: In the referred article $$\sin_n x=x-\frac{n}{3!}x^3 +o(x^3)$$ is given. We have here $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin_n x}{x}=1-\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{3!}x^2 +o(x^2)=-\infty.$$ This limit does not equal $1$. **Should you not have** $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}$ everywhere?

Comment: Thank you for thé typo, it is instead the limit as $x$ tends to zéro and not as $n$ tends to infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make another answer for the development of $\sin_n(x)$. Writing $$\sin_n(x)=x\Big(1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i\, x^{2i}\Big)$$ I obtained $$a_1=-\frac{n}{6}$$ $$a_2=\frac{n^2}{24}-\frac{n}{30}$$ $$a_3=-\frac{5 n^3}{432}+\frac{n^2}{45}-\frac{41 n}{3780}$$ $$a_4=\frac{35 n^4}{10368}-\frac{71 n^3}{6480}+\frac{67 n^2}{5670}-\frac{4 n}{945}$$ $$a_5=-\frac{7 n^5}{6912}+\frac{31 n^4}{6480}-\frac{1159 n^3}{138142}+\frac{121
   n^2}{18900}-\frac{136 n}{76257}$$ $$a_6=\frac{41 n^6}{132495}-\frac{295 n^5}{150767}+\frac{19 n^4}{3888}-\frac{488
   n^3}{82011}+\frac{443 n^2}{127295}-\frac{69 n}{89692}$$  $$a_7=-\frac{2 n^7}{20881}+\frac{63 n^6}{81982}-\frac{220 n^5}{86807}+\frac{527
   n^4}{121279}-\frac{310 n^3}{77043}+\frac{241 n^2}{128973}-\frac{21 n}{63916}$$ $$a_8=\frac{2 n^8}{66819}-\frac{12 n^7}{40871}+\frac{163 n^6}{133888}-\frac{224
   n^5}{81869}+\frac{499 n^4}{140556}-\frac{188 n^3}{72019}+\frac{121
   n^2}{123678}-\frac{7 n}{51549}$$I refuse to do any other !!

Comment: I just looked at $f(x)=\sin\sin x$ for which I get $$f(x)=-\frac{15788 x^{15}}{638512875}+\frac{15481 x^{13}}{97297200}-\frac{47 x^{11}}{49896}+\frac{13 x^9}{2520}-\frac{8 x^7}{315}+\frac{x^5}{10}-\frac{x^3}{3}+x$$ note that your expression says that the coefficient on $x^{11}$ should be $-\frac{21498129979}{22822789764600}$ (this corresponds to $a_5$ at $n=2$.)

Comment: @Math-fun. For sure, I could have done some mistakes (doing everything manually). I give up. You did not tell me how you made your calculations for the limits (a CAS, I presume, but which one ?). Have you been able to automate the curve fit and the generation of the expansions ? Please, let me know. Cheers :-)

Comment: ups sorry, I used Mathematica, wrote a little loop that does all the calculations ... I started to do things manually but then gave up ... I was not receiving enough fun out of doing it :-)

Comment: and the curve fitting was also automated using InterpolatingPolynomial, cheers :-)

Comment: @Math-fun. Just for my curiosity, could you send me the code by e-mail ? My address is is my profile. I am curious to see how you set the problem. So, I confess that, more than likely, my answers are wrong.

Comment: Sure, I would do so, maybe mine is wrong in the end, so would be great to have your opinion on the codes! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

Continuing in the same spirit as in my answer to the first question, we can probly admit that the limit could be expressed as a cubic polynomial in $n$. Going on with the expansions (tiring !!), I arrived to $${\sin _{n}(x)-x+\frac{n}{6}x^{3}-\left( \frac{ n^{2}}{24}-\frac{n}{30}\right) x^{5}}=-\Big(\frac{5 n^3}{432}-\frac{n^2}{45}+\frac{41 n}{3780}\Big)x^7+\cdots$$ which gives for the fourth limit $$L_4=-\frac{5 n^3}{432}+\frac{n^2}{45}-\frac{41 n}{3780}$$ Continuing with the next limit (very tiring !!) $$L_5=\frac{35 n^4}{10368}-\frac{71 n^3}{6480}+\frac{67 n^2}{5670}-\frac{4 n}{945}$$

At this point, I give up (hoping that I did not make any mistake with all these developments).

Answer (score 2):

In the tradition and notation of Claude:

$$L_6=-\frac{7 n^5}{6912}+\frac{31 n^4}{6480}-\frac{1631 n^3}{194400}+\frac{121 n^2}{18900}-\frac{3337 n}{1871100}$$

$$L_7=\frac{77 n^6}{248832}-\frac{3043 n^5}{1555200}+\frac{19 n^4}{3888}-\frac{6073 n^3}{1020600}+\frac{52093 n^2}{14968800}-\frac{28069 n}{36486450}$$

$$L_8=-\frac{143 n^7}{1492992}+\frac{2689 n^6}{3499200}-\frac{118243 n^5}{46656000}+\frac{66523 n^4}{15309000}-\frac{37945129 n^3}{9430344000}+\frac{3579391
   n^2}{1915538625}-\frac{228859 n}{696559500}$$

$$L_9=\frac{715 n^8}{23887872}-\frac{46027 n^7}{156764160}+\frac{85201 n^6}{69984000}-\frac{335093 n^5}{122472000}+\frac{133917919 n^4}{37721376000}-\frac{320023339
   n^3}{122594472000}+\frac{24679 n^2}{25225200}-\frac{5895983 n}{43418875500}$$

.
.
.

Comment: I was about to put similar stuff ... except that I did not go as far as you did.  May I ask how you made it ?

Comment: I observed that $L_j$ is a polynomial of order $j-1$, hence, say, to compute $L_4$ we need a polynomial of order 3 that passes through four points namely $$x_j=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin_j(x)-x-\frac j6 x^3-(\frac{j^2}{24}-\frac{j}{30})x^5}{x^7}$$ for $j=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: I agree but I am not sure about the results. I shall put another answer giving the expansion of $\sin_n(x)$. Please, tell me if I am correct. I sware I shall not do anymore !! Cheers :-)

Comment: I will check mine again, thanks for the comment :-) and I agree this is too much of "imposed fun" :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Direct computation**
$\def\wi{\subseteq}$

$\sin(x) \in x - \frac{1}{6} x^3 + \frac{1}{120} x^5 - \frac{1}{5040} x^7 + O(x^9)$ as $x \to 0$.

As $x \to 0$ and given function $f$ such that $f(x) \in x + a x^3 + b x^5 + c x^7 + O(x^9)$:

$\sin(f(x))$

$\ \in \left( x + a x^3 + b x^5 + c x^7 + O(x^9) \right)$

$\hphantom{\ \in} - \frac{1}{6} \left( x + a x^3 + b x^5 + O(x^7) \right)^3$

$\hphantom{\ \in} + \frac{1}{120} \left( x + a x^3 + O(x^5) \right)^5$

$\hphantom{\ \in} - \frac{1}{5040} \left( x + O(x^3) \right)^7$

$\hphantom{\ \in} + O(x^9)$

$\ \wi x + (a-\frac{1}{6}) x^3 + (b-\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{120}) x^5 + (c-\frac{1}{2}b-\frac{1}{2}a^2+\frac{1}{24}a^2-\frac{1}{5040}) x^7$

[Thus we can set up recurrences for $a,b,c$ on iteration of applying $\sin$ and solve them to finish.]

**Notes**

As you can see, we only need to handle the coefficient sequences. I'm too lazy to figure out the computational complexity of this algorithm in general but it is quite bad because the numbers grow exponentially. Is there a faster method? I doubt so. No wonder *Claude* got tired! But at least this is implementable on a computer and we don't have to do it ourselves for high order approximations.