# L'Hospital Rule with Trigonometry

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, derivatives

I've been working on this question for the final exam, yet I could not come to a closure. I'd appreciate if you can help me.

> What is $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(\sin(\sin x)) - x}{x^3}\qquad?$$

Comment: It's very easy to learn, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: do you know taylor series?

Comment: A little bit, but I'm allowed to solve this question only by using L'Hospital.

Comment: Thats one long hospital..

Comment: Actually I did the long calculations but it is too long to simplify. I think, I need to make a smart move to simplify somethings after the first one.

Comment: You can't really do anything until the denominator becomes a number, which means you must do it 3 times

Comment: by Taylor series it’s trivial and that’s the standard method to solve such limits, l’Hospital has a great theoretical value but it shouldn’t be used for limit calculation when they involve higher order infinitesimal

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhôpital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: I think it's not duplicate because Faruk Şimşekli want to solve this problem by L'Hospital Rule.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: if you see the original question one of the answers (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345338/72031) uses L'Hospital's Rule, so that question covers L'Hospital's Rule also. But like close votes one can use reopen votes too and its OK if the community so desires.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Now I see it. I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin\sin\sin{x}-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos\sin\sin{x}\cos\sin{x}\cos{x}-1}{3x^2}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\tfrac{-\sin\sin\sin{x}\cos^2\sin{x}\cos^2x-\cos\sin\sin{x}\sin\sin{x}\cos^2x-\cos\sin\sin{x}\cos\sin{x}\sin{x}}{6x}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\tfrac{-\tfrac{\sin\sin\sin{x}}{\sin\sin{x}}\cdot\tfrac{\sin\sin{x}}{\sin{x}}\cdot\tfrac{\sin{x}}{x}\cdot\cos^2\sin{x}\cos^2x-\cos\sin\sin{x}\cdot\tfrac{\sin\sin{x}}{\sin{x}}\cdot\tfrac{\sin{x}}{x}\cdot\cos^2x-\cos\sin\sin{x}\cos\sin{x}\cdot\tfrac{\sin{x}}{x}}{6}=$$
$$=\frac{-1-1-1}{6}=-\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Lol this isn't wrong, if this is what OP was going for then its correct, but perhaps they are supposed to see a better way

Comment: Yes, that's the way, but I can not get the transition from the second to the third. You did something I could not understand.

Comment: @Faruk Şimşekli I added something. See now.

Comment: very nice derivation!

Answer (score 5):

Consider the function
$$
f_n(x)=\underbrace{\sin\sin\dotsb\sin}_{n\text{ times}}\,x
$$
where $f_0(x)=x$. With a recursive formula, $f_{k+1}(x)=\sin(f_k(x))$; note that $f_k(0)=0$ and $f_k$ is continuous and invertible in a neighborhood of $0$.

Then your limit can be written as
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\left(
\frac{f_3(x)-f_2(x)}{x^3}+
\frac{f_2(x)-f_1(x)}{x^3}+
\frac{f_1(x)-f_0(x)}{x^3}
\right)
$$
so we may as well ask what's
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(f_k(x))-f_k(x)}{x^3}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f_k(x)-f_k(x)^3/6+o(f_k(x)^3)-f_k(x)}{x^3}
$$
Thus we just need to check what's
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f_k(x)}{x}
$$
The limit is $1$ for $k=0$; suppose we know that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f_k(x)}{x}=1
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f_{k+1}(x)}{x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(f_k(x))}{f_k(x)}\frac{f_k(x)}{x}=1
$$
using the fact that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Then your limit is
$$
-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{6}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$

More generally,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f_k(x)-x}{x^3}=-\frac{k}{6}
$$

Comment: very nice derivation!

Answer (score 3):

Do not use l’Hospital here!

Let’s use $$\sin {(x)} =x-\frac{x^3}6+o(x^3)$$

As an alternative you could try with the substitution:

$$x=\arcsin y$$

Comment: Yes ok of course we need n=3!

Comment: Do use L'Hospital's Rule. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345338/72031

Comment: @Paramanand Singh very clever and interesting solution! Thanks for the hint. In general I don like use LHR but algebraic manipulation are a good way to solve. If you can’t solve by it then Taylor series is always my first choice.

Comment: Agree with your comment. In my answer I made use of L'Hospital's Rule to find limit of $(x-\sin x) /x^3$ and this can be done even more easily with Taylor.

Answer (score 3):

This answer tries to clarify egreg's answer by using the function at hand instead of general functions.

If we can use that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}=-\frac16$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$, then
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\sin(\sin(x)))-x}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{[\sin(\sin(\sin(x)))-\sin(\sin(x))]+[\sin(\sin(x))-\sin(x)]+[\sin(x)-x]}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\color{#C00}{\sin(\sin(x))})-\color{#C00}{\sin(\sin(x))}}{\color{#C00}{\sin(\sin(x))}^3}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\color{#C00}{\sin(x)})^3}{\color{#C00}{\sin(x)}^3}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)^3}{x^3}\\
&+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\color{#C00}{\sin(x)})-\color{#C00}{\sin(x)}}{\color{#C00}{\sin(x)}^3}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)^3}{x^3}\\
&+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}\\
&=-\frac16\cdot1\cdot1-\frac16\cdot1-\frac16\\
&=-\frac12
\end{align}
$$